# A Hard-Luck Farmer

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

I work on a farm, but it's not as romantic as you think: I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work, and I get paid just 4 pennies per minute. I had to take a second job to pay the bills. Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment, but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

What is my name?

(A correct answer should explain all the clues, and I'm looking for a specific, non-fictional human being. The clues are not meant to be taken literally.)

(P.S. I removed the 'room and board' bit because it was just in there for flavor, but folks ended up reading into it. I should have realized that people would see it as a clue, so sorry about that.)

Hint 1:

> Synonyms are important.

Hint 2:

> Only one of the clues is a pun.

Hint 3:

> Why would someone on a farm wake up around sunrise?

Hint 4:

> Each main clue refers to a thing of mine which are all (more-or-less) of the same kind.

Bonus Clue 1:

> I wish I had a job I was more passionate about.

Bonus Clue 2:

> I have to put in a heroic effort just to get out of bed.

Comment: As I feel I shouldn't give a downvote without explaining... Although I had a bit of fun trying to solve this puzzle, mainly I found it frustrating. And now that the answer has been revealed, I find it requires what I would call specialised knowledge, and there is no indication anywhere that it required said specialised knowledge. (FYI - I recognise the person, and I *may* vaguely recognise Bonus Clue 2).

Comment: I understand your frustration, and I do think this was crafted in a way that left it too broad and vague. I'm a fan of the sort of puzzle that requires not just critical thinking, but depth of knowledge (or good research skills), but in the future I'll try and make it clear just what I'm looking for.

Comment: I do like puzzles that require a bit of knowledge, but for me this one required too much knowledge. It's a difficult balance between making it too obvious and making it too obscure. But I look forward to your next puzzle, as I did very much like the idea behind this one.

Comment: @AndyT Just as an FYI, I found the answer only by searching for all forms of rooster / cockcrow / daybreak, while assuming that it had something to do with a song title, book/poem title, movie reference etc. I eventually found something buried underneath all the references to Bongos Ikwue... =) http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NfqRy1Y-Tf8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> **Beethoven!**

I work on a farm

> The name Beethoven means **beet garden** ("hoven" is plural of "hof", which is German for "farming estate"). It is generally believed that the Beethoven family came from a line of Catholic farmers.

but it's not as romantic as you think

> Beethoven straddles the Classical and **Romantic eras** of Western classical music. Although a composer in the Romantic Period, his work, especially his earlier sonatas, were not very Romantic in style.

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work

> **The Cockcrow** (Violin Sonata No. 10 in Gmaj, Op. 96)

and I get paid just 4 pennies per minute

> It's easy to **Rage Over a Lost Penny** when you earn so little (Rondo a Capriccio in Gmaj, Op. 129)

I had to take a second job to pay the bills

> Taking two jobs is *moonlighting* (Piano Sonata No. 14 in C#m, Op. 27, No. 2, also known as the **Moonlight Sonata**)

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment

> **Consecration of the House** (Die Weihe des Hauses, overture, Op. 124)

but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen

> **Sonata Pathétique** (Piano Sonata No. 8 in C minor, Op. 13)

Bonus hint 1:

> *I wish I had a job I was more passionate about.*
>  Beethoven slowly became **deaf** which became a small obstacle in his enjoyment of music. He was also known for a **troubled love life**, which impacted the frequency and tone of his compositions, as well as the quality of his performances.

Bonus hint 2:

> *I have to put in a heroic effort just to get out of bed.*
>  "The Cockcrow" was one of the last pieces written in the **Heroic period** of Beethoven's life.

Comment: Hail our new puzzling overlord!

Comment: Congratulations Hackiisan!

Comment: (At least, I assume you're correct. It's by far the best answer anyone's come up with!)

Comment: Ding ding ding- we have a winner! Your answers to some of the clues are not correct, but it was a tough puzzle, so I'll award the bounty. Very nice thinking here! The answers that could use work are for the 4 pennies (we had a discussion about pre-decimal currency that might prove useful- perhaps if you think in terms of pfennigs instead of pennies, the answer will be clearer). The apartment answer is also not correct- this one is the pun, and it refers to a quite famous work of his. The two bonus hints also refer to works, and they are extremely straightfoward, so do with that what you will!

Comment: Yes, I just realized that the bonuses were "clues", not "hints", which means at least the answer to Bonus clue 1 is wrong. You are probably referring to the Apassionata then?

Comment: Indeed, and that would make the second one...

Comment: And of course Bonus clue 2 then simply refers to the Eroica.

Comment: Just so. The others are more difficult, but I will point out that it's specifically 4 pennies, and deliberately not 240 cents an hour- just something to chew on.

Comment: Well, if it's specifically four, then clearly a Kreutzer is worth about 4 pfennigs. The apartment one I still not sure. Perhaps a sonata in "A Flat Major"? In that case, the most famous one is the Funeral March (Op. 26).

Comment: Correct for the Kreutzer, but not quite for the apartment- that's not a bad pun, actually, but not the one I was looking for. It's one of his most recognizable and well-known pieces, and the pun is truly groan-inducing

Comment: uggggh ... "Fur Elise" => for Elise (a lease)

Comment: *groans loudly and facepalms*

Comment: Hate me if you must, but I really wanted to get that piece in there, and this was the only way to do it. Anyways, great work again, and I hope you enjoyed the puzzle!

Comment: I did! And it was an appreciative groan, hehe. Excellent work in putting it together!

Comment: *Beethoven* is a Dutch name, not German (note the *van* rather than *von*).

Answer (score 9):

Does not nearly fit all the clues but hey! Why not.

You sir are:

> A solar panel.

I work on a farm, but it's not as romantic as you think:

> Solar farms are not the picturesque ol' mcdonald farm

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work,

> Solar panels start working at the rising of the sun.

and if you take out room and board, I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work.

> Seems like the amount of energy a solar panel could produce in a minutes cost.

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

> not sufficiently explained! (Do to the high initial costs of solar panels they can't be your sole source of income?)

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment, but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> Not sufficiently explained! (maybe it is hard to have solar panels in the city)

Comment: I like the lateral thinking! I did just clarify the problem to indicate that I'm asking for a name, so I guess now the question is, what would you name your solar panel?

Comment: No, this is patrick.

Comment: Sunny the solar panel

Comment: I love this answer anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Some ideas (that might help someone else get a full answer):

*I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work*

> Do we replace "wake up" and "sunrise" with synonyms and then interpret "around" in a cryptic-crossword sense? So "rise around dawn" would give the nonsense word *ridawnse*; maybe some other synonyms give a meaningful word.

*if you take out room and board, I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work.*

> Pennies is usually abbreviated to "p" (in the days before decimal currency was introduced in Britain, it was "d" instead). So maybe there's a word or phrase consisting of four p's (or four d's) plus synonyms for "room" and "board".

Here's a possible answer (though I doubt it's the intended one):

> "room board dddd" is an anagram of **Mr Brad Odd-Dodo**, which could be a man's name.

Another possible answer (again, probably not the intended one):

> Your name is **Patrick**, of course!

Comment: +1 for some decent starts. You're onto something with part 1, but don't think so hard about it. In part 2, I find it interesting that you're thinking about pre-decimal currency...

Comment: @Patrick Maybe it's a [groat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourpence_(British_coin))? Then his name could be Joey, or "room board groat" is an anagram of "go abroad, Mr Root". Joey Root? :-P

Comment: You're thinking too hard about it :)

Comment: I want to meet this Brad Odd-Dodo

Comment: @Al.Sal Unfortunately he's dead now, along with the rest of the dodos.

Comment: So if sunrise = dawn, then "waking up around dawn" could be waking up next to your significant other, who happens to be named Dawn. Know anybody famous with a wife named Dawn? Or how about "wake up around dawn" - the word "yawn" is close to (i.e. "around") the word "dawn", and you might yawn when you wake up. Not sure where that gets you though.

Comment: @AndyT Not quite, but can you think of any other synonyms for sunrise?

Comment: @PatrickN Daybreak? Sunup? Morning?

Comment: @randal'thor Not quite what I'm looking for. Think about the context.

Comment: @randal'thor Consider the general context of the riddle. The meaning I intended for 'minute' is based on the unit of time

Comment: Actually, I'm going to add a hint based on this

Comment: @PatrickN In pre-decimal currency, 4 pennies per minute is a pound per hour! Is there a book/film/song/something called " pound per hour" maybe?

Comment: @randal'thor I had tried that avenue of thought, but couldn't come up with any leads.  Then again, music isn't my strong suit.

Comment: @McMagister Even YOU are stumped? :-O The OP said I was onto something with part 1, and my latest guess at a synonym for sunrise is "morn" (dawn, daybreak, sunup, and morning are all out). Romornuse? Wamornke? I dunno. Music and films aren't my strong suit either, but Google always helps!

Comment: @randal'thor Wow, that's an amazing and entirely coincidental happenstance! You know, I wonder if there were ever any other currencies that could be subdivided by 240... And as for sunrise synonyms, one or two other folks have come across an answer with some merit. Remember, it's what happens at sunrise on a farm that's important here.

Comment: @PatrickN rise around cock ... not as romantic ... sad sack ... is the answer something dirty? :-o

Comment: @randal'thor No, it is not something dirty. Look at AndyT's answer for some guidance in this regard

Answer (score 5):

You are

> Jeffrey Dean Morgan, the actor.  You were in the following movies:

I work on a farm,

> Texas Killing Fields

but it's not as romantic as you think:

> P.S. I Love You

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work,

> Red Dawn

and I get paid just 4 pennies per minute.

> Watchmen

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

> The Courier

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment,

> The Resident

but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> The Losers

(Bed and Breakfast)

> Dead & Breakfast

Comment: +1 for the closest answer yet! You're definitely thinking in the right direction in terms of what the clues refer to- the person I'm thinking of is in a different line of work, but you're getting there. Keep it up!

Comment: Aha! So an actor's movies are *close*, but you want someone in a different line of work. Well in that case we are very probably talking about a singer, with the clues either describing song titles or song lyrics. A couple of days ago I had "4 pennies per minute", with minute=60th=diamond, giving me "pennies and diamonds for a kiss" from Call me Maybe by Carly Rae Jepson. But I couldn't make that follow through to any of the other clues.

Comment: And now I've got "4 pennies per minute" as "diamonds are forever" by Shirley Bassey. But, again, I can't find any songs to match the other clues. Arrrghhhh!!! This question is so frustrating!

Comment: Yes, or author and their book(s). Or if it is still movies, then maybe a director instead of actor.  Time to put the old thinking cap back on.

Comment: @AndyT You're almost there- you still have to think just a little bit outside the box you're in right now. Pay attention to the bonus clues- they're much more straightforward than the other clues. When you figure out who it is, they'll seem so obvious that you'll hit yourself in the forehead.

Answer (score 4):

This is a looong way from matching every clue, but maybe it's a start...

If you work on a farm and need to be up for sunrise it's because:

> You are a cockerel, or cock; sunrise being the cockcrow

This also works with not being romantic because:

> Although some people might try and pull [The Naked Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Man_(How_I_Met_Your_Mother)) on a date, it's not very romantic...!

So clearly your name is ***not*** (because it doesn't match with any other clues!):

> Alfred Hitchcock. (Only famous person I could think of who matched my small part [pun *very* much intended] of an answer)

Comment: New thought: "room and board" might be "bed and breakfast", known as "B&B". So maybe you need to remove the letter B twice from... some word from either the previous or following clause

Comment: You are correct in two respects- it's not Alfred Hitchcock, and this is certainly a start

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit of a hail mary, but I'll throw it up and see what happens.

The hard luck farmer is:

> Andrew Luck, quarterback for the Indianapolis Colts

I work on a farm.

> The Colts' practice facility is the Indiana Farm Bureau Football Center

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work.

> Really reaching here, but it looks like there is a chain of breakfast restaurants, named Sunrise Cafe, in and around Indy.

And if you don't count room and board, I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work.

> Nothing definitive here.  I looked at his average yearly salary but got nowhere, and can't get my mind away from quarter back.

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

> Staying away from the Buffalo Bills here and instead I'll go with the set of DirecTV Luck is now featured in, though having looked at his salary, I don't think he's hurting for money.  Nonetheless, commercial acting is a second job.

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment.

> To be moving on up, a la The Jefferson's? Really grasping at straws with that one, but my sense of humor is satisfied with that as an answer, so I'll go with it.

But I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> Quarterbacks get sacked and that cuts into their success.

What is my name?

> Again, I'll say that it's Andrew Luck, and I'll let my mind create further justification out of "10 or 11 reads", and manipulate it to #12 reads (the coverage).  The third hint was just added, and it kinda rattles my conviction, but Luck is a specific, real person, with his name in the title.

Comment: +1 for a very nice attempt- I wish I was clever enough to make clues based on regional restaurant chains :)

Answer (score 2):

could it be,

> Mr. Potato Head

I work on a farm, but it's not as romantic as you think

> A potato is found on a farm and a couch potato probably doesn't make very romantic love on a couch since they're lazy

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work,

> Potatoes grow the most when the sun is out

if you take out room and board, I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work.

> Couch's collect pennies at a very slow rate or it could be that potatoes are very cheap and there worth the farm is probably about 4 pennies but I don't know about the first part of that

I had to take a second job to pay the bills. Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment, but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> Couch potatoes aren't very motivated so they only do the minimal amount of work

Also,

> All of these have to do with potatoes and the only person I can think of with potato in their name is Mr. Potato Head. Might be a bit of a stretch but I like my answer at least

Comment: Nice and along the lines of what I initially thought, but Patrick is looking for a "human being" :c

Comment: @Doge Ah dang I read that as specific name.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is not correct. I gave another clarifying edit that might help.

Answer (score 2):

***Partial Explanation***

Is it

> tennis player [Richard Gasquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Gasquet)?

I work on a farm:

> Thanks AndyT. A farm, as in a tennis court.

but it's not as romantic as you think

> He's a good tennis player, so he rarely gets "love".

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work,

> He's sponsored by [Le Coq Sportif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Coq_Sportif)

I'm stuck after that.

Comment: +1 I like it. I'm still completely stuck on what on earth most of the clues can mean!

Comment: +1 Very clever! Alas, not what I was looking for. @AndyT, the most important piece of info is hint 4- the clues each refer to a thing belonging to this person, and these things are all (more-or-less) of a kind. Some of the clues are synonyms, one is a pun. Hints 5 and 6 are much more straightforward than the other clues, so they could be a good starting point. Once you figure out what type of thing all the clues are referring to, it should all become very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Closest I have found so far.

You are

> Bob Dylan, the musician. My clues relate to my songs:

I work on a farm, but it's not as romantic as you think:

> "Maggie's Farm"

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work,

> "House of the Rising Sun" - though this is a cover.

and I get paid just 4 pennies per minute.

- Have not found a fit.

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

- Have not found a fit.

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment,

> "I Am a Lonesome Hobo"

but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> "Man of Constant Sorrow"

Comment: Mm, not quite. You're just about in the ballpark, at least in terms of what line of work this person is in.

Comment: Hmm, okay. It is a little tricky because as far as I am understanding there isn't any clues regarding the line of work or the name of the person just clues about things they have/created. Seems like you are expecting us to guess/process of elimination our way to a name and then find things they made that match the clues.

Comment: There is, in fact, a clue related to this person's line of work, and it's quite specific. In retrospect, it would have been helpful to have more, but the puzzle stands as is.  Regarding finding the name, from your perspective, if it was someone like Bob Dylan, you would have to come up with the name and then find songs that fit. However, it should be possible (based on how the puzzle is constructed) to guess at a couple of the clues and then find the person based on their correlation. Pay attention to the bonus clues- they're extremely straightforward, relative to the rest of the puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will try again on my lunch break! :P

Answer (score 1):

Well I had to use some creative googling based off of a single pun.

> [image: Duckington]

Am I jesting, surely not. You sir are:

> Farmer Duck!

I work on a farm.

> He works on a farm.

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work.

> He does all the work, that is how it works on farms.

And if you don't count room and board, I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work.

> Pennies is a term which can be used to describe chicken food, so it makes sense for a duck to be compensated with pennies.

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

> THE SWEET SWEET PUNNING. He has a bill. In order to feed his bill, he has to get a second job! (I have not read farmer duck but based on the attire from the picture looks like he has sellable skills)

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment.

> He does not seemed pleased with his living situation

But I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> He looks sad in his picture... :(

What is my name?

> Farmer Duck!

Alas,

> I have not read the tale so I could not tell of its congruence with my statements but it has a pun, if only one.

Comment: So i found farmer duck on youtube, other than being a gem of a kids book, it did not have much about jobs nor pennies so that made me sad. But I do recommend it for leisure viewing/reading, its a gem.

Comment: Although this does fit to some degree, and I do appreciate the pun, unfortunately the clues are not meant to be taken literally! If you're getting nowhere, Hint 4 is very important, and Hint 5 is a lot more straightforward than the other clues, so it may help.

Answer (score 1):

You are, very clearly

> Someone with the surname "Love". Googling *celebrities with the surname "Love"* gave me results of: Courtney Love, Jennifer Love Hewitt, and a whole stream of... er... employees of the "adult entertainment" industry...

I work on a farm:

> A farm has a field, if it was a field of grass you could maybe play tennis on it, making it a Court(ney)

but it's not as romantic as you think:

> This is a clue to the surname "Love"

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work
(***Disclaimer***: Do not open this spoiler if you are easily offended):

> This is something to do with cockcrow or cockerel. It may work for the "adult entertainers", as they definitely get a lot of, erm, "cockerel"...

if you don't count room and board:

> Room and board = bed and breakfast... no idea where to go with this

I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work:

> A minute is a 60th of an hour. "60th" in a different sense means *diamond*. Courtney Love was in the news for losing some diamonds.

I had to take a second job to pay the bills:

> Well, "The Bill" is a phrase used in the UK to refer to the police. Courtney has been arrested for various drugs misdemeanours, so maybe this is something to do with being arrested and fined?

I'd do anything just to get an apartment:

> An apartment can be called (in the UK at least, not so sure about US) a *flat*. With all the plastic surgery, Courtney's face is definitely *not* flat, so I think I've got that one wrong.

I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen:

> Is Courtney a bit grumpy normally? I don't really know, I barely know who she is.

I wish I had a job I was more passionate about:

> Well, she's a celeb so doesn't really have any job. And the "passionate" thing is referring to her surname "Love" again.

So, in summary you are:

> Courtney Love. And probably not an "adult entertainment" star.

Comment: A good effort, but not quite there. The 'adult' answer gets a bit off base, but keep thinking about it- if the clue isn't referring to a literal rooster, and it's not referring to adult entertainment, what could it it be? Hint 4 may be helpful.

Comment: @PatrickN - Yep, I thought the adult entertainment angle was unlikely! I hear you use the word "rooster" - interesting... I would never have thought of that myself (we have cockerels in the UK), so I'll give that some further thought.

Comment: Don't read too much into that- just the terminology here across the pond. What's important is what happens at sunrise (or, rather, what else we could be talking about here, because of course this isn't a literal cockcrow)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be,

> One of the members of Pink Floyd (Roger Waters maybe?) The album Animals is loosely based on George Orwell's book Animal Farm so maybe him? I don't know who the person is really

I work on a farm, but it's not as romantic as you think

> The song Pigs

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work

> Welcome to the Machine.  Getting up everyday for the daily grind of work, a.k.a. the machine

and I get paid just 4 pennies per minute

> Time

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

> Money

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment

> Nobody Home

but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> Goodbye Blue Sky. Whoever this is has no hope

Comment: Not quite- a few of these answers are a bit of a stretch. For at least some of the clues, especially the bonus ones, you should be able to find the name of the thing just based on the clue, instead of having to try and find something afterwards that fits.

Comment: @PatrickN Am I on the right track of music though?

Comment: I'd say that you aren't far off, but you aren't exactly close, either.

Answer (score -2):

You are

> Kimi the sweatshop worker

I work on a farm, but it's not as romantic as you think:

> Many sweatshop workers start out on their family farm in the countryside

I need to wake up around sunrise to go to work, and if you take out room and board, I get just 4 pennies for every minute of work.

> They have to work horrendous hours and can get awful wages (which are often more than they'd make on the family farm)

I had to take a second job to pay the bills.

> Kimi went from her family farm to the city where she works in a factory for Nike.

Honestly, I'd do anything just to get an apartment, but I'm such a sad sack it'll probably never happen.

> Idk, like omg. She sends a lot of her money home to feed her family?

Comment: Well, it's an interesting answer, but not correct- a sweatshop worker could be named anything, so there wouldn't be a single answer in that case.

Comment: Well I saw you asked Going hamateur for the name of his solar panel so I named my sweatshop worker but then you changed the question :P

Comment: Yeah, I edited to clarify